# Not seeing submitted data in Django when I do an Ajax post

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, django

This is my html page:

```
<div>
<form id="assignment_form" action="/submit-assignments/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- Fields here -->
    <select id="user_list" multiple='multiple' size="10">
    {% for u in users %}
        <option value="{{ u.iduser }}" >{{ u.get_long_name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <select id="assigned_list" multiple='multiple' size="10" style="width: 200px">
    </select>
    <input id="assign" type="submit" value="Assign"/></input>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
        //cookies stuff
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#assignment_form").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"/brewkeep/submit-assignments/",
                data: $("#assignment_form").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                     alert(data);
                }
            });
       });
    });
</script>
```

This is my Django view:

```
def submit_assignments(request):
    print request.POST
    return HttpResponse("Success!")
```

After I click my `Assign` button, I look at the screen output, this is what I see printed:

```
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'LqSWcQDMt8YGoBqpBMw8B8mfebC9ZyEo']}>
```

How do I access my submitted data?

Thanks!

Comment: Do your fields have `name`s?

Comment: Yes, they have ids. I have two multiple-select lists that I can move stuff between.

Comment: ids are not enough. They must have `name` attributes to be submitted.

Comment: Do you have your url's setup correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Your `select`s must have a `name` attribute:

```
<select id="user_list" name="user_list" multiple='multiple'  size="10">
{% for u in users %}
    <option value="{{ u.iduser }}" >{{ u.get_long_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
<select id="assigned_list" name="assigned_list" multiple='multiple' size="10" style="width: 200px">
</select>
```

[HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls):

> A successful control must be defined within a FORM element and must have a control name.

[w3schools `<input>` name Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp):

> *Note:* Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form.

Comment: I'm still not getting anything for some reason.

Comment: Did you select anything in the `select`s?

Comment: Yes I have stuff in the selects.

Comment: Yea, but do you have anything actually *selected*, highlighted?